# Primefaces Dialogs Form Structure

Tags: primefaces

I'm using Primefaces for a project and I'm seeing bad results with IE vs chrome/firefox/safari in regards to modal Primefaces dialog windows and I think it has to do with form placement.  In IE these dialogs dont appear, but I can see the transparency.  In chrome/firefox they're fine.  What is the best practice for the below situations:

> List item base xhtml page that has one form.  This page has several
>   links that open up dialogs who have their own ajax submit
>   (commandButton, commandLink) events.

Should the dialog be located within or outside the base xhtml page's form?
Should the dialog have its own form?

Below is an illustration:

```xml
<html>
    <ui:composition>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="xyz">
                //main page content here, commandButtons, commandLinks...etc
            </h:form>
            <dc:zoomDialog/>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>

<!-- zoomDialog maps to the below -->
<html>
<ui:component>
    <h:form id="dialogFrm"> 
        <p:dialog widgetVar="zoomDlg" modal="true" styleClass="dialog dialog2"
                draggable="false" resizable="false" showEffect="fade"
                hideEffect="fade">
            //dialog content here, commandButton, commanLink...etc
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</ui:component>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see it in your example code but some time ago I had a similar problem. The reason was: nested forms (the same symptoms as you describe: all browser work, except IE). Nested forms are not valid html. Some browsers can handle it. IE cannot.

A good test is to put the whole html outpout (browser source, not the jsf source) into the [W3C Html validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and analyze the results.

In the [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf) the `h:form` element is always inside the `p:dialog`. See [this discussion](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2958).

Comment: link broken: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf?jfwid=71409